# Java Nested Loops Issue

Tags: java

so I've been working on this code for a while now, and I've reached a standstill. It's a project for school and it came in two parts, the first part was no issue at all.

> A drunkard begins walking aimlessly, starting at a lamp post. At each time step, the drunkard forgets where he or she is, and takes one step at random, either north, east, south, or west, with probability 25%. How far will the drunkard be from the lamp post after N steps?
>
> Write a program RandomWalker.java that takes an integer command-line argument N and simulates the motion of a random walker for N steps. After each step, print the location of the random walker, treating the lamp post as the origin (0, 0). Also, print the square of the final distance from the origin.

My code for this part of the problem was:

```
import java.util. *;
import java.math. *; 

public class RandomWalker {

public static void main(String args[]){
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int XorY;
    int dist;
    int count =0;

    while(count<N){
        XorY = rand.nextInt(2);
        dist = rand.nextInt(2);   
        if(XorY==0){
            if(dist==0)
                dist = -1;
            x += dist;
            System.out.println("("+x+", " +y+")");
        }
        else{
            if(dist==0)
                dist = -1;
            y += dist;
            System.out.println("("+x+", " +y+")");
        }
        count ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Squared Distance = " + (x*x + y*y));
  }
}
```

For the second part of the problem-

> Write a program RandomWalkers.java that takes two command-line arguments N and T. In each of T independent experiments, simulate a random walk of N steps and compute the squared distance. Output the mean squared distance (the average of the T squared distances.)

```
% java RandomWalkers 100 10000
squared distance = 101.446 

% java RandomWalkers 100 10000
mean squared distance = 99.1674 

% java RandomWalkers 200 1000
mean squared distance = 195.75
```

The code I came up with is-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RandomWalkers {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int T = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    double avgDist =0;
    int stepCount =0;
    int trialCount =0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int XorY;
    int dist;
    
    while(trialCount<T){
        while(stepCount<N){
            XorY = rand.nextInt(2);
            dist = rand.nextInt(2);
            if(XorY==0){
                if(dist==0)
                    dist = -1;
                x += dist;
            }
            else{
                if(dist==0)
                    dist = -1;
                y += dist;
            }
            stepCount ++;
        }
        avgDist += ((x*x) + (y*y));
        trialCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Mean Squared Distance = " + avgDist/(double)trialCount);
  }
}
```

I have been stumped here for a really long time, the code compiles and runs but it seems that all it is giving me is a single trial value, and not the desired average. Any help is appreciated, thank you very much. (Also sorry for the improper formatting, I am new here and tried my best).

Comment: Your class `RandomWalkers` should make use of `RandomWalker`.  The only data you need to get from a single simulation (`RandomWalker`) is the distance.  Therefore, `RandomWalkers` should not have to concern itself with X's and Y's.  Just accumulate the sum of squares and divide by the number of simulations `T`.

Comment: Hint (not directly related to your question): in your `RandomWalker`class, you can pick a random direction by drawing a single random integer in the range 0 to 3 (for N,E,S,W), and just use four `if` for each of them (or one `switch` statement).

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the nested `while loop` inside the `for loop` is shown below. You have to reset the `x`, `y` and `distance` variables after each trial. Or, even better, to define and initialize them to 0 at the beginning of the for `loop`, like so:

```
public class RandomWalkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        double steps = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < trials; j++) { // run one experiment

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int distance = 0;

            while (distance < r) { // simulate one random walking
                double i = Math.random();

                if (i < 0.25) {
                    y += 1;
                    distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                    steps += 1;
                }
                if (i >= 0.25 && i < 0.5) {
                    x += 1;
                    distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                    steps += 1;
                }
                if (i >= 0.5 && i < 0.75) {
                    y -= 1;
                    distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                    steps += 1;
                }
                if (i >= 0.75 && i < 1) {
                    x -= 1;
                    distance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
                    steps += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("average number of steps = " + steps / trials);
    }
}
```